# Pandas: Using .isin() returns the error: "AttributeError: float' object has no attribute 'isin'"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using Pandas and Python to import a CSV, and the data in the imported dataframe is manipulated so that a new column is made.

Each row in the new column is made based on the values in each corresponding row of both column A and column B.
There are more columns with data in the dataframe, however these are irrelevant for code below.

The imported dataframe have several thousand rows.

Both column A and column B contain numerical values between and including 0 and 99.

import pandas as pd

```
import csv

df = pd.read_csv("import.csv", names=["Id", "Month", "Name", "ColA", "ColB" ])

def f(row):
    if row['colA'].isin([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 48]) and  row['colB'].isin([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 57, 58]):
        val = row['ColA']
    elif row['ColB'].isin([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 48]) and  row['ColA'].isin([30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 57, 58]):
        val = row['ColB']
    elif row['ColA'] > row['ColB']:
        val = row['ColA']
    elif row['ColA'] < row['ColB']:
        val = row['ColB']
    else: 
        val = row['ColA']
    return val            

df['NewColumnName'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)   

df.to_csv("export.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

Running the above code returns the error:

```
AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

So obviously .isin() can't be used in that manner. Any suggestions to how this could be solved?

**EDIT**
Adding a column where the same conditions apply using Jezrael's approach the code would look as follows I guess:

```
m1 = (df['colA'].isin(L1) & df['colB'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColA'] > df['ColB'])
m2 = (df['colB'].isin(L1) & df['colA'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColA'] < df['ColB'])
m3 = (df['colC'].isin(L1) & df['colB'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] > df['ColB'])
m4 = (df['colB'].isin(L1) & df['colC'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] < df['ColB'])
m5 = (df['colC'].isin(L1) & df['colA'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] > df['ColA'])
m6 = (df['colA'].isin(L1) & df['colC'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] < df['ColA'])



df['NewColumnName'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6], [df['ColA'], df['ColB'], df['ColC'], df['ColA'], df['ColB'], df['ColC'],], default=df['ColA'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas the best is avoid loops, so better is use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and chain condition by `&` for `AND` and `|` for `OR`:

```
L1 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 48]
L2 = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 57, 58]

m1 = (df['colA'].isin(L1) & df['colB'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColA'] > df['ColB'])
m2 = (df['colB'].isin(L1) & df['colA'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColA'] < df['ColB'])

df['NewColumnName'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df['ColA'], df['ColB']], default=df['ColA'])
```

Comment: Elegant solution. I assume that the value in colA is selected (from the part of the code that says: default=df['ColA'] ) when the value in ColA equals the value in ColB?

Comment: @BoroBorooooooooooooooooooooooo - No it is default value if no condition match, it is same logic like  `else:  val = row['ColA']`

Comment: If one wants to add columns, let's say ColC and with same conditions. Would be it be the correct to add:
' m3 = (df['colC'].isin(L1) & df['colB'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] > df['ColB']) '
'm4 = (df['colB'].isin(L1) & df['colC'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] < df['ColB'])'
m5 = (df['colC'].isin(L1) & df['colA'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] > df['ColA'])
m6 = (df['colA'].isin(L1) & df['colC'].isin(L2)) | (df['ColC'] < df['ColA'])
df['NewColumnName'] = np.select([m1, m2, m2, m4, m5, m6], [df['ColA'], df['ColB'], df['ColC'], df['ColA'], df['ColB'], df['ColC'],], default=df['ColA'])'

Comment: I added that code to the main post as I can't seem to format it as code here in the comment section.

Comment: hmmm, you can chain condition again, so use `df['NewColumnName'] = np.select([m1|m4, m2|m5, m3|m6], [df['ColA'], df['ColB'], df['ColC']], default=df['ColA'])`

Comment: Thank you very much! That is interesting, seems better than repeating ' df['ColX'] ' in the choicelist part. Here we could say comma and | in the conditions-list don't affect the end result differently I assume.

Comment: As a side note: I wonder if generative AI can be unbanned for a moment to suggest less spammmmmmmmmmmmmy usernames?;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use it like this:

```
df[df['ColA'].isin([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 48])]
```

This will give you the rows where `ColA` value is in the list that is indicated above. You are trying to do it per value, however this method applies on whole column. If you want to see if one value is in this list then you can write something like this in your function using numpy:

```
if np.any(row['colA'] == [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 48]):
   val = row['ColA']
```